How to detect back button and forward button in Firefox?
My goal
I am developing an online mouse tester, where users can test left/middle/right/forward/back button. I use mousedown event and MouseEvent.button to detect buttons. It works on Chrome 127.0.6533.88 . It doesn't work on Firefox 128.0.3 .
Reproduction

Open the JS Bin live demo (you may need to click "Run with JS")
In Chrome, click forward button and back button, and you will see 4 and 3 in the console
In Firefox, click forward button and back button, and there will be no output in the console

Live demo: https://jsbin.com/qucofakebi/1/edit?html,console,output
Demo code:


document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(e.button);
  return false;
})




Can you please explain what you mean by forward and back button?

The forward button and back button are typically located on the side of a mouse. They function similarly to the right arrow button and left arrow button in a browser, allowing you to navigate forward or back through your browsing history.

@thecodingsage the buttons that go forwards and backwards in history. Usually situated on the side of the mouse, where the thumb is.

Ohh, i have used a mouse like that but i never why it was for. But my current mouse sadly doesn't have those buttons.

Note that these are technically programmable buttons, and are just "thumb buttons", not necessarily acting as forward/back at all. Unlike the left and right mouse buttons, which you can absolutely rely on to be forward and back. That said: sounds like a bug, if I were you I'd report that over on the bugzilla tracker for Firefox, because programmable buttons that aren't hardware switches (e.g. enabling/disabling smooth scroll, changing the mouse resolution, etc) should still generate a mouse event.
